# How to express check for unique pair of values in regardless of order in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I'm in need of expressing pathing data in sqlite3 database. I have graph and I need to save shortest paths between some vertexes. Now, since my graph is bidirectional, shortest path between A and B will be the same as path between B and A.

My current db structure looks likes this:

```
create table shortest (
    id1 long,
    id2 long,
    ...
);
```

Now, how can I express constraint that `(id1, id2)` must be unique **regardless the order**? So if I try to insert `insert into shortest values (2, 1, ...)` and there already exists record with `(1, 2, ...)`, the insert will fail?

I cannot figure this out :/

NOTE: changing db structure is ok if it's  needed, this is a new project.

Comment: Does SQLite support indexes on expressions? In Postgres you would use: `create unique index idx_id_unique on shortest (least(id1,id2), greatest(id1,id2))`

Comment: looking at it documentation I would say that no, it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, this could be solved with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER shortest_unique_path
BEFORE INSERT ON shortest
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'reverse path already exists')
    FROM shortest
    WHERE id1 = NEW.id2
      AND id2 = NEW.id1;
END;
```

However, it might be easier to just introduce an additional constraint that a path must be inserted with the smaller vertx first:

```
CREATE TABLE shortest (
    id1 LONG,
    id2 LONG,
    ...,
    UNIQUE(id1, id2),
    CHECK(id1 < id2)
);
```

Comment: the `check(id1 < id2)` is nice and short solution, thank you :)